# Centered text overlay on image that is object-fit & object-position (CSS GRID)

Tags: html, css, image, responsive, css-grid

I'm wondering if it's possible to have a centered text overlay (caption) on an image that is object-fit: contain; AND object-position: left top; (ie. not centered)

Image is being displayed in CSS Grid. (Display: Grid;)

Example of what I'm trying to do:

[image: Example]

[image: *********** ANOTHER EXAMPLE: I would also like to be able to do centered captions for portrait ratio images ***********]

```css
.container {
  height: 40vw;
  width: 40vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:grid;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: left top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/A825/production/_103954034_gettyimages-990971906.jpg">
</div>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: why not simply making the image as background? with background-size:contain and background-position:top left

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) controls how replaced content fits within its container. You do not have access to the replaced content in terms of layout and positioning. A way to achieve the effect you're wanting within a grid would be to add a new container, set some `width`/`height` attributes on your image based on the container values and then position your text relative to that image, avoiding the use of Object Fit.

```css
.container {
  align-items: start;
  height: 40vw;
  width: 40vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:grid;
}

img {
  display: block;
  height: auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-height: 40vw;
  max-width: 40vw;
}

.textcontainer {
  position: relative;
}

.textcontainer-x-text {
  color: limegreen;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-weight: bold;
  left: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<p>Portrait</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="textcontainer">
    <div class="textcontainer-x-text">Example Text Which Could Be Long</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/150x400">
  </div>
</div>

<p>Landscape</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="textcontainer">
    <div class="textcontainer-x-text">Example Text Which Could Be Long</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x150">
  </div>
</div>

<p>Square</p>
<div class="container">
  <div class="textcontainer">
    <div class="textcontainer-x-text">Example Text Which Could Be Long</div>
    <img src="http://placehold.it/300x300">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's one of the many solutions:

Use the `position: relative;` on the `.container`, then `position: absolute;` on the text (here I used a `h3`) to relocate it, using a `-10vh` from `top`.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/660/cpsprodpb/A825/production/_103954034_gettyimages-990971906.jpg">
  <h3>LOREM IMPSUM</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  height: 40vw;
  width: 40vw;
  border: 1px solid black;
  display:grid;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height:100%;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  object-position: left top;
}

h3 {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -10vw);
  top: 20vw;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer. I have also added an example for when I have a 'portrait' ratio image. Please see 2nd screenshot attached. If you have any ideas for 'portrait' ratio format, please let me know. Thank you!

Comment: Same principles, this time you only have to center the text on vertical and evaluate the width that is taking the image.